# Request Variable on each run

Tags: paw-app

I'm using paw to test our API as well as run customer support for various problems that occur. Right now we're using request variables to manage the parts of the API call both URL or Body that are variable. However, its common for us to forget to update a value. Is there a type of request variable we can use that would require a new value for each run? Something like a pop up with a dynamic form for the values required by the request?

Answer (score 1):

I using Paw too and need to send every request with new value. I'm using request variable and fill it with **JS Script** that contains `return +new Date();`

In that way If i sending requests not more than once per microsecond it contains new value.

[image: 1]]

Comment: This is cool but not sure it solves our problem. Timestamp has a `now` box you can check that auto updates the date. But the problem we have for example is updating a user, its possible to forget to update the userID in the request, so the values you send could be going to the wrong user. (A big part of this is why you shouldn't do meaningful support through an API).

Ideally we could create a request variable without a value and when running that request, it would ask for that required value.